# When there is repetitive code in React, is it better to put them in an array and render using map or just write the entire markup manually?

Tags: reactjs, react-component

First way:

```
    function SampleComponent(){
     const data = [Hello, World];
     return (
       <div>
       { data.map(x => <ChilComponent name={x} />) }
       </div>
    }
    
    function ChildComponent(){
      return( <h1> {name} </h1>
    }
```

Second way:

```
   function SampleComponent(){
     return (
       <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <h1>World </h1>
       </div>
    }
```

In my original code the child component has the same attributes and classNames except the name that its taking. But there are only like 5 elements that I have to render. I am unsure on which way is more optimized and why. Please explain.

Comment: You can use an array but you don't have to create a new `ChildComponent`. What's wrong with `data.map(value => <h1>{value}</h1>)`?

Answer (score 0):

I think a quick and easy answer to this question in the exact provided use case would be better to just manually render the elements like you have in the second solution.

*Assuming the text "Hello", "World" are **NOT** dynamic and are specific to that component alone:*

**My reasoning** here is that I think it makes sense that it would be less optimized (at least performance wise) in the first way. Obviously, the performance shouldn't be a concern in this case, but I think it still illustrates the point. The second way is a bare bones approach and is just rendering to the DOM. The first way does the same approach as the second, except it needs to create an array, then traverse that array before executing the same approach as option 2.

Now, if you are asking from a strictly code readability / re-usability point of view, I may answer slightly differently...

*Assuming `data` is going to be a prop from the parent and is **NOT** just hard coded strings like in the example:*

Thinking of this from a outside perspective as someone coming to work on the project for the first time, I would much rather see the data being converted into an array like you have in the first approach. It is much cleaner / pleasing to read and I feel it will be less prone to accidental bugs or typos.

I think this does come down to a decent amount of personal choice in the end for this example. I have seen very good programmers do these in both ways, and give very good arguments for each.